# SQLAlchemy 'character_set_name' error in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql

After deploying application to Google App Engine this warning  is raised on (what it seems like) random requests.

```
/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py:2452: SAWarning: No 'character_set_name' can be detected with this MySQL-Python version; please upgrade to a recent version of MySQL-Python.  Assuming latin1.
```

The sql server is Google Cloud SQL.

Is there a way to fix it (maybe set `character_set_name` to some value) or it is totally dependent on the MySQL-Python version shipped with App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this issue if I used:

create_engine('mysql+gaerdbms:///xxx?instance=xxx:xxx')

but, it goes away if you use:

create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/xxx?unix_socket=/cloudsql/xxx:xxx')